# Python Given a date, time, hour... how can i get it's formated ISO ZULU

Tags: python, datetime

I have been using python IMAP protocol and I read email headers and retrieve the Date which looks like

```
myDate --> Fri, 22 Feb 2019 17:00:06 +0000
```

I need to find the equivalent UTC ISO8601 with zulu formatting how can I do that?

I tried:

```
dateInUTCIso= datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +%f').date().isoformat()
```

but I am only getting year/month/date

```
dateInUTCIso= 2019-02-22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.date()` method call

```
myDate = "Fri, 22 Feb 2019 17:00:06 +0000"
dateInUTCIso= datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +%f').isoformat() + 'Z'
# 2019-02-22T17:00:06Z
```

Comment: ok I did it n fact I also tried --> datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +%f').replace(tzinfo=simple_utc()).isoformat().replace ('+00:00', 'Z')   this gives me --> 2019-02-22T17:00:06Z  I am a bit confused is this UTC ISO ZULU or is this 2019-02-22T17:00:06+00:00?

Comment: See my edited answer for the format you are looking for. the `+00:00` is stripped automatically, so simply appending 'Z' is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `.date().isoformat()`. Without `.date()` you would get the ISO format.

However, if you want Z instead of +00:00 at the end, you'll have to swap out that part after the fact with `.replace('+00:00', 'Z')` on the string output

Comment: Thanks Jim I also asked Liam   I also tried --> datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +%f').replace(tzinfo=simple_utc()).isoformat().replace ('+00:00', 'Z') this gives me --> 2019-02-22T17:00:06Z I am a bit confused is this UTC ISO ZULU or is this 2019-02-22T17:00:06+00:00?

Comment: 2019-02-22T17:00:06+00:00 and 2019-02-22T17:00:06Z are both acceptable representations of the same point in time in the same timezone under ISO8601. The Z actually doesn't stand for Zulu time (GMT) under ISO8601 (it stands for Zero offset from UTC). UTC ISO ZULU doesn't really exist but when UTC and GMT are the  same they represent the same thing.